# How can I apply Bootstrap 5 validation to a Razor form?

Tags: validation, bootstrap-5, razor-pages

I have Razor Pages form like this:

```
    <form id="account" method="post">
        <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
        <div class="form-floating mb-3">
            <input asp-for="Input.Email" class="form-control" autocomplete="username" aria-required="true" />
            <label asp-for="Input.Email" class="form-label"></label>
            <span asp-validation-for="Input.Email" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
...
```

in the output i get the following render:

```
    <form id="account" method="post">
        <div class="form-floating mb-3">
            <input class="form-control" autocomplete="username" aria-required="true" type="email" data-val="true"
                data-val-email="The Email field is not a valid e-mail address." data-val-required="The Email field is required."
                id="Input_Email" name="Input.Email" value="">
            <label class="form-label" for="Input_Email">Email</label>
            <span class="text-danger field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Input.Email" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
        </div>
...
```

But Bootstrap v5 uses the `:invalid` and `:valid` styles applied to form controls.
At the same time, `data-val-` attributes are not taken into account in any way.

Is it possible to seamlessly connect the Bootstrap 5 validation functionality on the client while retaining all the power of customizing the Razor Pages validation model?

Comment: No need to mention jQuery. Bootstrap doesn't require it and you haven't tagged it, so there's no reason to expect answers that use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading the [documentation for the ValidityState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ValidityState) object and the [JS Forms API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form). And by combining this with [Bootstrap Validation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/forms/validation/), we got the following solution for the following validation properties: `valueMissing`, `typeMismatch` (email), `tooLong`, `tooShort`. The list is not complete, the solution can be developed to suit your needs.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    (() => {
        'use strict'

        function validateControl(c) {
            c.addEventListener('input', (event) => setErrMessage(c));
        }

        function setErrMessage(c) {

            const name = c.getAttribute('name');
            const errMsg = Array.from(c.parentElement
                .querySelectorAll(`[data-valmsg-for="${name}"]`))
                .filter(msg => !!msg.getAttribute('data-valmsg-replace'));

            errMsg.forEach(msg => msg.innerText = '');

            c.required = !!c.getAttribute('aria-required');

            const requiredErrorMessage = c.getAttribute('data-val-required');
            if (requiredErrorMessage && c.validity.valueMissing)
                errMsg.forEach(msg => msg.innerText = requiredErrorMessage);

            const typeMismatchErrorMessage = c.getAttribute('data-val-email');
            if (typeMismatchErrorMessage && c.validity.typeMismatch)
                errMsg.forEach(msg => msg.innerText = typeMismatchErrorMessage);

            const lengthMax = c.getAttribute('data-val-length-max');
            const lengthMin = c.getAttribute('data-val-length-min');
            if (lengthMin)
                c.setAttribute('minlength', +lengthMin)

            const lengthErrorMessage = c.getAttribute('data-val-length');
            if (lengthErrorMessage && (c.validity.tooLong || c.validity.tooShort))
                errMsg.forEach(msg => msg.innerText = lengthErrorMessage);

        }

        // Fetch all the forms we want to apply custom Bootstrap validation styles to
        const forms = document.querySelectorAll('form')
        // Loop over them and prevent submission
        Array.from(forms).forEach(form => {

            form.noValidate = true;

            const controls = form.querySelectorAll('[data-val="true"]');

            Array.from(controls).forEach(validateControl);

            form.addEventListener('submit', event => {

                Array.from(controls).forEach(setErrMessage);

                const isValid = form.checkValidity();

                if (!isValid) {
                    event.preventDefault()
                    event.stopPropagation()
                }

                form.classList.add('was-validated')

            }, false)
        })
    })()
</script>
```